# NSNumberFormatter through StoryBoard - Xcode 9

Tags: cocoa, storyboard, nsnumberformatter

I want to implement NumberFormatter through Storyboard, for currency inputs in textfields.

I have referred to these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7479950/7205816
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30688762/7205816

This makes me believe that it was there in  earlier Xcode versions. Is it the same case now? How can we implement it in storyboard?

If we do it through code, the issue I am facing is that I convert it into comma separated string, but need to save the same without commas.

What is the correct way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NSNumberFormatter** is only available for mac apps. To have the same behavior on iOS you should do it programmatically.

---

In Xcode 10:

In the UI components Library, search for Text Field with Number Formatter

[image: search]

Then in the scene explorer, select the Number Formatter:

[image: scene]

In the Attributes Inspector, you could set the properties of the number formatter:

[image: attributes]

---

On Xcode 9 and lower, you can find the UI Elements in your storyboard by toggling the inspector panel:

[image: ui elements]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using Xcode 9 currently, so are the steps same? I am unable to find the UI components Library

Comment: Choose a Currency Style for currency inputs.

Comment: @Dia You'll find it in the inspector at the bottom right like [here](https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2017/05/SizeClasses-2.gif)

Comment: @Carpsen90 The gif is of size classes. I still cannot find the UI Components Library in it. Please upload a gif of whole process if possible

Comment: @Dia have a look at the right bottom. (It's just a gif a found on the internet)

Comment: @Dia Are you creating a project for MacOS? or iOS?

Comment: For iOS - iPad only

Comment: @Dia NSNumberFormatter is only available for mac apps. To have the same behavior on iOS you should do that programmatically. But that would be a totally different question

Comment: @Carpsen90 Thanks for the answer. Will post another one in that case. Please put this comment as a part of the answer. I will accept it.